# HotSpot JVM options/jmap output

Tags: java, jvm

When I running my java application on Hotspot VM using following configuration:
**-Xms2048m**, **-Xmx2048m**, the **jmap** outputs:

```
Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio = 70
   MaxHeapSize      = 2147483648 (2048.0MB)
   NewSize          = 1310720 (1.25MB)
   MaxNewSize       = 17592186044415 MB
   OldSize          = 5439488 (5.1875MB)
   NewRatio         = 2
   SurvivorRatio    = 8
   PermSize         = 21757952 (20.75MB)
   MaxPermSize      = 85983232 (82.0MB)

Heap Usage:
PS Young Generation
Eden Space:
   capacity = 706740224 (674.0MB)
   used     = 364788568 (347.88948822021484MB)
   free     = 341951656 (326.11051177978516MB)
   51.61565107124849% used
From Space:
   capacity = 4587520 (4.375MB)
   used     = 1900560 (1.8125152587890625MB)
   free     = 2686960 (2.5624847412109375MB)
   41.428920200892854% used
To Space:
   capacity = 4456448 (4.25MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 4456448 (4.25MB)
   0.0% used
   ...
```

What makes me confused is why the capacity of eden space and two survivor space doesn't obey the formula

`eden/(s0+s1) = SurvivorRatio`

But when I add another jvm option **-Xmn500m**, the **jmap** outputs seems reasonable, i.e. the capacity obeys the formula strictly

Answer (score 0):

I wish this would get a bit more attention... Indeed you are right (this is not an answer - but too long for a comment)

When I do:

```
 java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal | grep SurvivorRatio
      uintx InitialSurvivorRatio                     = 8
```

Clearly this is **8**. But when testing it's acting more like a **6** (I can't reproduce your HUGE difference that you are seeing with **jdk-8**).

Here is the relevant parts when running with **-Xmx2048m -Xms2048m**

```
 PS Young Generation
 Eden Space:
 capacity = 537395200 (512.5MB)
 ....
 From Space:
 capacity = 89128960 (85.0MB)
 ....
 To Space:
 capacity = 89128960 (85.0MB)
```

That is:

> 512/85 = 6

As soon as I ran the same code with the same **-Xmx2048m -Xms2048m**, *but add the default value* : **-XX:SurvivorRatio=8**; the output is:

```
 PS Young Generation
 Eden Space:
 capacity = 573046784 (546.5MB)
 ....
 From Space:
 capacity = 71303168 (68.0MB)
 ....
 To Space:
 capacity = 71303168 (68.0MB)
```

> 546.5 / 68 = 8.

The same is true for **-Xmn** - that you are setting. And this is weird! I have not changed the value of `SurvivorRatio` - it is still the same default 8.

It seems that internally there are some checks whether flags related to the computation of `SurvivorRatio` are being set and different policies applied(I wish I knew the intrinsics of these, but no luck).

And *boy!* did I try to find these. I did find *something* that hints towards that, but not directly an answer, like [this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/runtime/arguments.cpp#l1573) or [this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/parallelScavenge/generationSizer.cpp#l58) (especially the comment). I did a :

```
  grep -R "SurvivorRatio" .
```

inside the `hotspot` sources locally and still no hint in all the results of what is going on.

---

The only logical explanation I have at this point in time, is that *unless specified* any parameter related to `SurvivorRatio`; a default value will be chosen (that is not necessarily the one reported by `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal`), but something in the middle, something close to that. If this is the case, then it should **clearly be specified in the documentation**; otherwise in my world this is a tiny documentation bug.

Comment: I have found the source code related to this issue. I think this may be helpful.  [psYoungGen.cpp](https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_hotspot/blob/master/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/parallelScavenge/psYoungGen.cpp) . From line 108 to line144