# Why -Xmn1m -XX:SurvivorRatio=2 makes eden space 0k

Tags: java, jvm, java-7

I set `-Xmn1m -XX:SurvivorRatio=2`, expect to see eden space to be `512K`, but actually it is `0K`.

It is really strange and I don't know why. I need your help.

> vm options :-Xmx20m -Xms20m -Xmn1m -XX:SurvivorRatio=2
>   -XX:+PrintGCDetails
>
> java version: 1.7.0_79

code and result is as followed:

```
public class NewSizeDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        byte[] b = null;

        for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
            b = new byte[1*1024*1024];
        }
    }
}
```

```
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 512K, used 0K [0x00000007fff00000, 0x0000000800000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 0K, -2147483648% used [0x00000007fff00000,0x00000007fff00000,0x00000007fff00000)
  from space 512K, 0% used [0x00000007fff80000,0x00000007fff80000,0x0000000800000000)
  to   space 512K, 0% used [0x00000007fff00000,0x00000007fff00000,0x00000007fff80000)
 ParOldGen       total 19456K, used 11573K [0x00000007fec00000, 0x00000007fff00000, 0x00000007fff00000)
  object space 19456K, 59% used [0x00000007fec00000,0x00000007ff74d5a0,0x00000007fff00000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 2996K [0x00000007f9a00000, 0x00000007faf00000, 0x00000007fec00000)
  object space 21504K, 13% used [0x00000007f9a00000,0x00000007
```

Answer (score 2):

I did some experiments with Java 7 and Java 8 and different options. The key point seems to be

- Spaces have always sizes that are multiples of `512k` and can’t be empty, so the smallest setup is “eden `1×512k`, from `1×512k`, to `1×512k`”, which implies that you can’t have a new size smaller than `1536k`. Also, the ratio constraint can only respected as far as possible with whole-number factors of the `512k` unit size.
- The numbers you specify are subject to rounding to multiples of `512k` and enforcing the minimum size of `512k` for each space, which is the first place showing inconsistencies. E.g. using `Xmn1m` with Java 8, I got a warning that the `NewSize` of `1536k` (apparently already adapted) exceeds the `MaxNewSize` of `1024k` (apparently not adapted yet), which is confusing as `Xmn1m` is supposed to set both to the same value, so saying that both are too small would be more understandable. Also, the warning only showed when using `Xmn1m`, resp. `Xmn1024k`, which are not subject to rounding, but was not shown for `Xmn1023k` or `Xmn1025k`.
- Since the JVM doesn’t crash with that option, the adaptation seems to always result in reasonable values, but the code printing the statistics seems to have bugs (in Java 7 only), mixing the attempted configuration numbers with the numbers actually used by the JVM.
- The total size reported for the Young Generation always includes the *eden* and *from* space only, ignoring the always-empty **to** space, which is inconsistent to the addresses reported behind the sizes, which include the complete span, covering all three spaces.

Comment: somehow related I think: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43798527/hotsot-jvm-options&ved=0ahUKEwiz4IyYqbLXAhUCCewKHYOnAokQjjgIIjAA&usg=AOvVaw0D3I5GbJFe9_6olMMqlaRK

Answer (score 2):

This is a **JVM bug** introduced between JDK 7u40-b27 and JDK 7u40-b28.
Bug report JDK-8016309 is not publicly open.

Before JDK 7u40 the minimum size of heap region was 512 words (4KB). With the given JVM arguments the Eden size was correctly set to 512K:

```
 PSYoungGen      total 768K, used 287K [0x00000000fff00000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 512K, 56% used [0x00000000fff00000,0x00000000fff47e08,0x00000000fff80000)
  from space 256K, 0% used [0x00000000fffc0000,0x00000000fffc0000,0x0000000100000000)
  to   space 256K, 0% used [0x00000000fff80000,0x00000000fff80000,0x00000000fffc0000)
```

[JDK-6725714](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6725714) increased the minimum region size to 65536 words (512KB).
Here is the [related change](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/hsx/hsx25/hotspot/rev/5534bd30c151#l2.7). The same change has broken the sizing policy.
This resulted in assertion failure in debug builds of JVM:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (/home/hotspot/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/parallelScavenge/psYoungGen.cpp:183), pid=10261, tid=1081264448
#  assert(eden_size > 0 && survivor_size > 0) failed: just checking
#
```

There was no assertion failure in product builds, but rather the weird behavior you've observed.

The problem was noticed and fixed in JDK 8. The minimum possible size of young generation became 1536KB. I guess the fix was not suitable for backporting, so the bug remained in later updates of JDK 7.

However, it was decided to document the problem in [JDK 7u40 release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u40-relnotes-2004172.html):

> **Area**: hotspot/gc
>   **Synopsis**: New minimum young generation size is not
>   properly checked by the JVM.
>
> In JDK 7u40, the minimum size of the young generation for the parallel
>   garbage collector was increased from 192 KB to 768 KB in a 32-bit JVM,
>   and to 1536 KB in a 64-bit JVM. This new minimum size is not properly
>   checked by the JVM. If a young generation size that is smaller than
>   the new minimum is specified on the command line, it can result in
>   either a crash or degraded performance.
>
> The young generation size is set by the options -XX:NewSize= and
>   -XX:MaxNewSize=, or by the option -Xmn (the latter option is equivalent to setting both NewSize and MaxNewSize to ). If the
>   above options are not used, then the young generation size is computed
>   as a fraction of the maximum heap size.
>
> **Workaround**: Use a young generation size that is at least 768 KB (for
>   32-bit JVM) or 1536 KB (for 64-bit JVM).