# PSYoungGen is not the sum of "eden", "from" and "to"?

Tags: java, java-8, garbage-collection, jvm-hotspot

I have a simple demo to check the details of JVM memory allocation & deallocation.

The Java Version

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

The Demo

```
/**
 * VM Options: -Xms20M -Xmx20M -Xmn10M -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:SurvivorRatio=8
 */
public class DefaultCollector {
    private static final int _1MB = 1024 * 1024;
    public static void main(String... args) {
        byte[] arr1 = new byte[2 * _1MB];
        byte[] arr2 = new byte[2 * _1MB];
        byte[] arr3 = new byte[2 * _1MB];
        byte[] arr4 = new byte[4 * _1MB];
    }
}
```

I **manually** used the CLI to compile and run the program as

```
$ javac DefaultCollector.java 
$ java -Xms20M -Xmx20M -Xmn10M -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 DefaultCollector
```

The GC logs

```
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 9216K, used 6979K [0x00000000ff600000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 8192K, 85% used [0x00000000ff600000,0x00000000ffcd0f68,0x00000000ffe00000)
  from space 1024K, 0% used [0x00000000fff00000,0x00000000fff00000,0x0000000100000000)
  to   space 1024K, 0% used [0x00000000ffe00000,0x00000000ffe00000,0x00000000fff00000)
 ParOldGen       total 10240K, used 4096K [0x00000000fec00000, 0x00000000ff600000, 0x00000000ff600000)
  object space 10240K, 40% used [0x00000000fec00000,0x00000000ff000010,0x00000000ff600000)
 Metaspace       used 2468K, capacity 4486K, committed 4864K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 265K, capacity 386K, committed 512K, reserved 1048576K
```

#### My Question

1. `-Xms20M -Xmx20M -Xmn10M -XX:SurvivorRatio=8` already set and `eden: 8M, from: 1M, and to: 1M` presented clearly, why [PSYoungGen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/serviceabilityagent/sun/jvm/hotspot/gc_implementation/parallelScavenge/PSYoungGen.html#capacity--) `total 9216K` instead of `10240K`?
2. why [`Metaspace`](http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com/2013/02/java-8-from-permgen-to-metaspace.html) taking so much memory `Metaspace used 2468K`? what's in there exactly? Are there **only type information**?

Comment: Didn't I see this question about two or three hours ago?

Comment: Haha, yeah... but it's different in some aspects while that question already marked **solved**. This question now is focusing on the **unanswered** parts.

Comment: The discrepancy in the reported sizes has been noticed before and it was even worse in the past, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47192751/2711488) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43798527/2711488)…

Comment: @holger Wow, so crazy! Thank you so much for your **past** experiments which explained the first question perfectly. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47204548/2361308

Comment: The first question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27012218/3448419), the second - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53678418/3448419) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54250638/3448419).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the first question, @Holger has provided quite direct experiment to demonstrate the [fact](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47204548/2361308).

> The total size reported for the Young Generation always includes the eden and from space only, **ignoring the always-empty `to` space**, which is inconsistent to the addresses reported behind the sizes, which include the complete span, covering all three spaces.

Then when it comes to the second

> why Metaspace taking so much memory Metaspace used 2468K? what's in there exactly? Are there only type information?

I found its specification in [Java Platform, Standard Edition HotSpot Virtual Machine Garbage Collection Tuning Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/considerations.html#sthref66) as

> In the line beginning with Metaspace, the **used value** is the amount of space used for loaded classes...The line beginning with class space line contains the corresponding values for the metadata for **compressed class pointers**.